# Search Bar with UISearchControllerDelegate and/or UISearchBarDelegate and/or UISearchController

Tags: swift, function, uitableview, controller, protocols

I am a newbie in Swift and I want to implement Search Bar but it seems there is not so much tutorials on how to do it right with new protocols Apple introduced.

I have a named tuple with some data in it (name, category, details and so on, and they are of type String)

I have read documentation but I am still inexperienced and really don't know how to implement this new magic.

My question is how can I make `Search Bar and Search Bar Display Controller` (the former is deprecated) to work with my tuple?

Sample code is:

```
var myData = namedTuple(   category: "Lorem ipsum",
                           name: "Dolor",
                           details: "Some info on subject."
                       )

    objects.append(myData)

// and so on...

var objects = [myData]()
```

Answer (score 0):

See the video on [Vea Software](http://www.veasoftware.com/tutorials/2015/4/13/search-display-controller-in-swift-xcode-62-ios-82-tutorial), shows an example from the beginning how to use `Search Bar and Search Bar Display Controller`